# Common Lisp determine is a directory is a subdir or another directory

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am using hunchentoot to build a simple web app to expose a directory tree to the web. The problem I am having is finding a reliable and safe way to determine if the directory requested is actually a child directory of the `*share-root*` which is `/srv/share`.

I have spent time the cl-fad but it is not exactly what I need (or I am not using it in such a way as to solve my problem).

My goal is to be able to receive a path like: `/srv/share/media/../../../` and realize the request should be ignored because it is asking for something outside of the share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest [`enough-namestring`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_namest.htm) combined with [`truename`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_tn.htm): if

```
(enough-namestring foo bar)
```

is a relative pathname, then `foo` is under `bar`.
In other words:

```
(defun pathname-under-p (under top)
  (case (car (pathname-directory (enough-namestring (truename under)
                                                    (truename top))))
    ((nil :relative) t)
    (t nil)))
```

or just

```
(defun pathname-under-p (under top)
  (not (eq :absolute (car (pathname-directory (enough-namestring (truename under)
                                                                 (truename top)))))))
```

If your implementation does not support `truename` on a directory, you will have to use an implementation-specific function or [`directory`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_dir.htm).

Many thanks to @Svante for debugging.

Comment: `(enough-namestring #p"src/../" #p"src/")` returns `"src/../"` for me in SBCL 1.1.18 on Linux x64.

Comment: @Svante: does `(truename "src/../")` work? (see edit)

Comment: That gives me the absolute directory instead of a relative directory starting with `:up`, so `pathname-under-p` returns always true.

Comment: @Svante: you mean `enough-pathname` returns an absolute path?

Comment: Yes.  For me, you could replace `:up` with `:absolute` and it would work.  I am not sure whether this is a portable solution, though.

Comment: @Svante: I think I nailed it now, please test!  Thanks!

Comment: I am still not sure about portability.  Other implementations might choose to make the enough-path `(:relative :up #|...|#)`.  There is `uiop:subpathp`, but it seems to be restricted to absolute paths.